# Android BroadcastReceiver On Boot not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, toast, boot

I'm trying to run a simple on boot receiver. I just need to get one record from my database (which does exist - tested), I'm testing it with Toast message (is that possible?). Nothing happens when phone boots :

Receiver :

```
    public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    int milibaza;    


    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 


    Cursor cursor = DatabaseManager.getAllData(); 
    if(cursor !=null) 
    { 
    cursor.moveToFirst();    
    milibaza = cursor.getInt(2); 
    Toast.makeText(context, ((new StringBuilder("Vrijeme u bazi").append(milibaza).toString())), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
cursor.close();   
    }              
    } 
    }
```

Get all data method :

```
public static Cursor getAllData() 
    { 
        Cursor cursor=null; 
        if(db!=null)
        { 
            cursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { TABLE_COLUMN_ID, TABLE_COLUMN_ONE, TABLE_COLUMN_TWO }, null, null, null, null, null); 
        } 

        return cursor; 
        }
```

Values in manifest connected to receiver I'm trying to run :

```
 <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: I'd recommend instead of the toast (which I think should show), write to sharedpreferences, then in your main activity check if that value is true. It's a sure way to check in this scenario.

Comment: @A--C Okay, but first - are you sure there's nothing wrong in my code up there?

Comment: All I can see wrong is  `cursor.close();` is outside the if, so you can still get an NPE if `cursor` is `null`. Make an `else` with another toast, in that toast, output `"cursor is null"`.

Comment: For clarification, are you entering into the onReceive method? Try either putting a breakpoint in onResume or put a log statement as the first line in that method. Let me know if onReceive is being called at all.

Comment: @WindyB Yes I know I am, the receiver is being called because I had some errors before, application would crash because of some exceptions I had in the onReceive method. So yes.

Comment: If this is on boot, have you initialized your database at that point? It seems like the only other place this problem can be is with your DB logic.

Comment: @WindyB Yeah DB is okay and there is a record in it, I'm using the same methods for displaying data in a textview and it all works well. Also I have a listview with records and its all displayed as it should. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can launch the Toast using the context from the BroadcastReceiver onReceive() function. Try using an Intent to launch an Application Activity instead.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you actual run your application prior to booting up the phone. If you force stop the app before restarting, or you didn't run the app after installing your APK, your broadcast receiver will not receive any messages.

Comment: It seems I can confirm this.

Comment: Yes I've run the application after installing it and I didn't force close it before the phone restart.